# Fetch rows on PL SQL Loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Hi how do i use fetch rows on pl sql it seems like i'm getting an error when i use the select statement inside the loop but on the outside loop it seems to work.

here's my query

```
FOR z IN ( SELECT DISTINCT a.column1, a.column2, b.column3
               FROM table1 a,
                    table2 b,
                    table3 c,
           ORDER BY b.column3
           FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY) // doesn't work getting an error
      LOOP
          v_rec.column1   := z.column1;
          v_rec.column2    := z.column2;
          v_rec.column3  := z.colum31;    
      END LOOP;
```

here's the error i'm getting

> ERROR line 63, col 16, ending_line 63, ending_col 20, Found 'FETCH', Expecting:  (   identifier  REVERSE  or   *    +    -    :   AT  CASE  CAST  CLUSTER_ID  CLUSTER_PROBABILITY  CLUSTER_SET  CONNECT_BY_ROOT  CURSOR  DAY  decimal number  FALSE  FEATURE_ID  FEATURE_SET  FEATURE_VALUE  integer  MODEL  MULTISET  NEW  NULL  PREDICTION  PREDICTION_COST  PREDICTION_DETAILS  PREDICTION_PROBABILITY  PREDICTION_SET  PRIOR  SQL  string  THE  TREAT  TRUE  XMLELEMENT  XMLPARSE  XMLPI  XMLQUERY  XMLROOT  XMLSERIALIZE  YEAR

I'm trying to limit my rows by adding `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` on my SELECT statement.

Comment: `FETCH FIRST` works in Oracle 12c+, which version  are you using? Also, mysql<>Oracle, please don't include that tag for Oracle questions. Another important point : **Don't** use the implicit comma syntax for joins, switch to proper explicit `JOIN ON`

Comment: removed the "mySQL" tag as it seems to be irrelevant. Please don't tag things which are nothing to do with your question...thanks.

Comment: Apparently you are using and outdated Oracle version

Comment: @KaushikNayak how do i check my version of my oracle?

Comment: @KaushikNayak but it seems to work when i use it outside of the loop.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it works when i use the select query outside of the loop, why is that?

Comment: what is the benefit of using `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` if you are using it in a loop. what i understand from oracle compiler- it does not trigger the query every time for multiple row. it trigger the query once and then loop on it. And, if you always want one row, the you can use into clause.